# Populating Task Subtype field with Call when a task created

Tags: trigger, tasks

[image]I'm new to Salesforce development, I have a requirement to populate Task Subtype Field on task with 'Call' when ever a task is created with Account. This can not be done with workflow field update. If possible can any one provide me with a Sample trigger that populates value in task Subtype.

Comment: you can try with process builder and if you face any issues, post it here

Comment: Does not work even with process builder.

Comment: can you post a picture how you are trying

Comment: Add Screen shot for Process Builder. i'm not able to find the Field 'Task Subtype' when trying Field update or Record update

Comment: The issue might be that Task.TaskSubType is not updateable per the [SObject reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_task.htm?search_text=task) - since WFs and PB cant just operate on New records, there is an implicit assumption that the available fields need to be updateable as well as creatable

Answer (score 4):

`Task.TaskSubtype` is *createable*, but not *updateable*. This means it's amenable to being populated only at the time of the record's creation, without firing an `update` DML operations. Practically, that limits our options to the `before insert` trigger.

You can do this, for example:

```
trigger TaskTrigger on Task (before insert) {
     for (Task t : Trigger.new) {
         t.TaskSubtype = 'Call';
     }
}
```

and it'll work just fine... mostly.

The "mostly" has to do with how the Lightning Chatter publisher inserts Tasks. It doesn't populate the `TaskSubtype` field until some point between the `before insert` and `after insert` triggers, which means that you cannot see the `TaskSubtype` of a Task inserted via the publisher in your `before insert` trigger, and any changes you make to it get overwritten by the system.

Once you reach the `after insert` trigger, the field's already been "created", and it cannot be updated, so you no longer have the ability to modify it.

While I have not tried updating `TaskSubtype` in Process Builder, based on its position in the [order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm), I would not expect it to work.

(I have written a [post](https://www.ktema.org/2018/07/11/lightning-activities-view/) on this subject).

Answer (score -1):

You are definitely missing something as the field is accessible and here is a screenshot I took to guide you -

[image]

You should check to see Field Level Security and make sure you have access to that field or if the label has been changed in your org.

Answer (score -2):

It can't be done. Upvote this idea -

> ## [Make TaskSubType editable](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000COq5QAG)
>
> There is a new field on Task called TaskSubType. It would be very useful if this field was editable.
> There is an important reason for this:
> In LEX, tasks are filterable dependent on their TaskSubType value (Filter timeline) and the task also displays a different icon accordingly.
> We have emails imported into Salesforce as tasks from a 3rd party product and they appear as ordinary tasks as opposed to Emails.
> Please allow us to edit this field!

Comment: It can be done, but *only at the time of insertion*. The field is createable, but not updateable.